# Accessing Tracking Records with the Consumer API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I'm currently working on a project where I would need to Read and possibly update information from tracking records. I haven't found anything in the Knowledge Base that refers to any kind of tracking record (LoanApp, Account, Share, etc) access through the API. Is it possible to read and or update fields in any of the tracking records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much support for reading and updating tracking records (I'm assuing you mean SymXchange external tracking records) via the API. *Updating*, in particular, is not available.

For *reading*, one option may be to have the Banno Admin at the financial institution enable the *Restricted Claim* which is `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/external_tracking_records` (that's a *scope* name, not a URL). You'll want to read this page in the *Authentication Framework* docs: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/

The gist is that the claim (when enabled by the admin at the FI, and also requested by your code) provides SymXchange external tracking records as part of the [Identity Token](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm mainly talking about tracking records inside of episys. For example I have access to loan information, but not the loan tracking information. Is there anyway to access that information through the API?

Comment: Nothing beyond that restricted claim would be available.